# Import constatnts header from main project to Cocoa pod file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, header, cocoapods

I have a `.xcworkspace`. I have an `AppConstants.h` in my main project and I need to import it in a file within some library which is connected in CocoaPods project. How can I import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend you to do so,think about if you run PodInstall the next time, Your code would be overwritten.

What i would do, is just import the files as files, and not Cocoapods and then change them.

or you could build a Cocoapod your self and still use dependencies:

http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html